# Not sure if the token is being correctly and safely, mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, passwords, mongoose

Hey guys here is my mongoose schema with a way to create a user token that will be included in a password reset link, I was just wondering if it looked right? Also, not sure how to exactly call a new token, after the User has been created, will a User.save or User.findAndUpdate and then include the token work in the route file? Also, what do I insert inside the token field as a value that will draw from the token encrypted here?

Here is the file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var crypto = require('crypto');
var UserToken;

var UserSchema = new Schema({ 
    email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase:true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: Number, required: true},
    birthday: {type: Date, required: true},
    friendRequest: {type: Object},
    notifications: {type: Object},
    friend: {type: Object},
    date_created: {type: Date},
    token: {type: String}
}, {collection: "users"});

UserSchema.statics.new = function(_id, fn) {
    var user = new UserToken();
    crypto.randomBytes(48, function(ex, buff) {
        var token = buff.toString('based64').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-');
        user.token = _id + '|' + token.toString().slice(1,24);
        user._id = _id;
        user.save(fn);
    });

};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```